# numberOfRowsInSection: method for core data and multiple sections

Tags: core-data, rows, nsfetchedresultscontroller, sections

I am trying to show a table view with 2 sections.  The first section will always have 1 row and the second section will have as many rows as data points.  I am using Core Data and the following tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: method...

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
        return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
    }
}
```

However, I am getting the following error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason:
>   '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

Any help will be appreciated.  Thanks.

NEW -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

This is the current implementation of the relevant methods:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        NSUInteger frcSection = section - 1;
        id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:frcSection];
        return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}

- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        cell.textLabel.text = entityOne.name;  //entityOne object passed from previous VC
    } else {
        entityTwo = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.textLabel.text = entityTwo.name;
    }
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
  didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
           atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex
     forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
{
    NSUInteger frcSectionIndex = 0;
    frcSectionIndex = sectionIndex + 1;

    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:frcSectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:frcSectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
   didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
     forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that the fetched results controller (FRC) has only one section (**section #0**), which you want to be displayed in the second section (**section #1**) of the table view.

This is possible, but you have to map between FRC section numbers and table view section numbers, e.g.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        NSUInteger frcSection = section - 1;
        id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:frcSection];
        return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
    }
}
```

The same mapping is necessary in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

In the FRC delegate methods `didChangeObject`, `didChangeSection` you have to *add 1* to the section number before calling the table view methods (e.g. `insertRowsAtIndexPaths`).

---

**ADDED:** `configureCell` should look like this:

```
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        cell.textLabel.text = entityOne.name;  //entityOne object passed from previous VC
    } else {
        NSIndexPath *frcIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:(indexPath.section - 1)];
        entityTwo = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:frcIndexPath];
        cell.textLabel.text = entityTwo.name;
    }
}
```

and `didChangeObject` like this:

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
   didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
     forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;
    NSIndexPath *tvIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:(indexPath.section + 1)];
    NSIndexPath *tvNewIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:newIndexPath.row inSection:(newIndexPath.section + 1)];

    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[tvNewIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[tvIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:tvIndexPath] atIndexPath:tvIndexPath];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[tvIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[tvNewIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}
```

You probably get the idea:

- When going from FRC index path to table view index path, add one to the section.
- When going from table view index path to FRC index path, subtract one from the section.

Comment: Thank you. I have been able to do the mapping, as you explained, in the numberOfRowsInSection: and didChangeSection: methods. However, I am having a hard time doing the mapping in the cellForRowAtIndexPath: and didChangeObject: methods. Would you be able to help me with these two mappings?

Comment: @AveLeon: If you add your current implementation of these functions to your question, I can try to help.

Comment: Thank you. I just did. As you will see, I was not able to change the section number in the methods with Index Paths.

Comment: Thank you so much! This certainly helped!

Comment: Question: did you intentionally leave the indexPath intact in the NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate case?

Comment: @AveLeon: No, that was an error on my side, sorry. I have fixed the answer.